# Disable Espresso IdlingResource base on condition

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have following Espresso test :

```
    @Test
    fun testSearchItemFound() {
        onView(withId(R.id.action_search)).perform(click())

        onView(isAssignableFrom(EditText::class.java))
                .perform(typeText("Harry Potter"),
                        pressImeActionButton())

        // Check error message view is not displayed
        onView(withId(R.id.error_msg)).check(matches(not<View>(isDisplayed())))

        // Check the item we are looking for is in the search result list.
        onData(allOf(`is`<Any>(instanceOf<Any>(String::class.java)),
                withItemContent("Harry Potter")))
                .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    }
```

The first line of code :

```
onView(withId(R.id.action_search)).perform(click())
```

will be executed properly when EspressoIdlingResource is idle.

But last line of code:

```
onData(allOf(`is`<Any>(instanceOf<Any>(String::class.java)),
                withItemContent("Harry Potter")))
                .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
```

Will be executed when we have following code in MainFragment:

```
// The network request might be handled in a different thread so make sure Espresso knows
            // that the app is busy until the response is handled.
            EspressoIdlingResource.increment() // App is busy until further notice
            model.movies.observe(this@MainFragment, Observer<PagedList<Movie>> {

                // This callback may be called twice, once for the cache and once for loading
                // the data from the server API, so we check before decrementing, otherwise
                // it throws "Counter has been corrupted!" exception.
                if (!EspressoIdlingResource.getIdlingResource().isIdleNow) {
                    EspressoIdlingResource.decrement() // Set app as idle.
                }
                adapter.submitList(it)
            })
```

If I disable :

```
EspressoIdlingResource.increment() // App is busy until further notice
```

And :

```
if (!EspressoIdlingResource.getIdlingResource().isIdleNow) {
                    EspressoIdlingResource.decrement() // Set app as idle.
                }
```

First line works properly :

```
onView(withId(R.id.action_search)).perform(click())
```

Is there any solution to handle this exceptional case?

Source can be found at : https://github.com/Ali-Rezaei/TMDb-Paging/tree/master/app/src/androidTest/java/com/sample/android/tmdb